# Set screen focus to svg element d3js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, svg

I have a large d3 chart nearly 4000px x 9000px and I have one text box in which user gives input to search a particular node in chart. 
I have used flesler's ScrollTo plugin of jQuery to scroll my screen but issue is when zoom in/out is there then it is not able to locate the given object i.e. it is not moving the svg instated it is scrolling only page.
Is there any way to scroll svg along to locate the node in center of screen?
code snippets of flesler's plugin I'm using is

```js
 $.scrollTo($(".mySelector'), 800,{queue:true,offset:{top:-100,left:-1000},margin:true});
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: http://codepen.io/pdillon/pen/bEgmA my chart is looks similar to this (almost same except x-axis as time which will only zoom). Now lets say I want to find one path which have unique id and once I give command to locate that path it should appear in center of screen. I hope it will make my question a bit clear.